# How to access application constants from within a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application where a user can set up an account which has a public URL associated with it a-la-twitter, e.g. http://myapplication.com/user_directory

In order to make sure that the users can't chose directories that I want to reserve (home, help, settings etc) I have a list of these stored in a configuration file and loaded in via environment.rb.

**environment.rb**

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
MyApplication::Application.initialize!

APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
RESERVED_DIRECTORIES = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/reserved_directories.yml")
```

This works fine and I can access RESERVED_DIRECTORIES array from views however I can't access it from the User model.

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_exclusion_of :user_url_dir, :in => RESERVED_DIRECTORIES

end
```

**The problem**

```
uninitialized constant User::RESERVED_DIRECTORIES (NameError)
```

There is clearly a scope issue happening but I don't know what the correct syntax is to access the RESERVED_DIRECTORIES array from this model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urgh, I just realised why this wasn't working. I was declaring the constants after the app had been initialized.

**Doesn't work**

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
MyApplication::Application.initialize!

APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
RESERVED_DIRECTORIES = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/reserved_directories.yml")
```

**Does work**

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
RESERVED_DIRECTORIES = YAML.load_file("#

# Initialize the rails application
MyApplication::Application.initialize!
{Rails.root.to_s}/config/reserved_directories.yml")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider moving RESERVED_DIRECTORIES to the User model itself, which gives you automatic namespacing of a sort, and should work in your code and specs

I would also consider defining reserved directories directly in the code instead of in a yaml file, assuming you don't have 500 of them, since this is a constant I do not believe it will be synced with the file anyway after the initial load.

```
class User
  RESERVED_DIRECTORIES = ['app','private','admin']
end
```

...call with

```
validates_exclusion_of :user_url_dir, :in => User::RESERVED_DIRECTORIES
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Unfortunately there are a very large number of these directories (~100) and I'm also following a pattern of keeping all app constants in the config directory. I just don't know how to access them :S

Comment: Wrap them in a class in application.rb?  AppConstants < ActiveDirectory::Base...call with AppConstants::RESERVED_DIRECTORIES?  Unfortunately not sure why constants are not avail

Comment: just figured it out (see my answer). Frustratingly obvious!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to put constants like this in your `config/application.rb` file, for example:

```
module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    RESERVED_DIRECTORIES = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/reserved_directories.yml")
    ...
  end
end
```

This way your constant is scoped to your application and can be accessed like this (from anywhere):

```
MyApplication::Application::RESERVED_DIRECTORIES
```